# js make later get window variable; don't init var until this var is called

Tags: javascript

I expect set window variable before its inner class defined, so I make following code

```
Object.assign(window, {
    get C2() {
        return C
    }
})

class C {

}

new C2()
```

but it raise `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'C' before initialization`, I know put class C def before Object.assign can fix this err, but my confused is why following code cannot later get

```
Object.assign(window, {
        get C2() {
            return C
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The `C` class you name is actually referenced as soon as you call `Object.assign`, the `get C2()` property that is created contains a reference to `C` that must be known when `Object.assign` is called.

If the `C` class name is not known when `Object.assign` is called, then JS doesn't know what should be assigned.

Comment: Yes just to add, nested functions in classes are loaded inline with the class. If there isn't a previous definition it will not compile. Compiler loads local scope before global (usually), is more clear.